# Is the localization of a polynomial ring at a prime ideal a valuation ring if and only if the prime ideal is principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

> Is the localization of a polynomial ring at a prime ideal a valuation ring if and only if the prime ideal is principal?

It seems to me that it is the case, and here's my work on the question in the form of an argument:

Suppose $R$ is an integral domain, let $\mathfrak p$ be a principal prime ideal of $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ generated by $p$. We note $\text{Frac}(R[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{\mathfrak p}) = R(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. Suppose $f \in R(x_1, \dots, x_n)$. If both the numerator and the denominator are divided by $p$, then $f$ is equivalent to some other $f'$ s.t. $p$ divides either only the numerator, or only the denominator. Clearly then, $f'$ or $f'^{-1}$ is in $R[x_1,\dots, x_n]_{\mathfrak p}$

Conversely, consider the localization of a polynomial ring at a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ that is not principal. Then $\mathfrak p$ has at least two generators, $a,b$. But $a/b \in R(x_1,\dots, x_n)$, yet neither $a/b$ nor $b/a$ are in $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{\mathfrak p}$, establishing the desired proposition.

Comment: This is a follow-up to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713170/is-the-localization-at-a-prime-ideal-of-any-polynomial-ring-always-a-valuation-r

Comment: I think the “converse” direction needs more work. After all, your argument seems to work for rings of integers of number fields – except that they can contain non-principal prime ideals and all their localizations at nonzero primes are DVRs. When $R$ is a Noetherian UFD, the equivalence holds (because $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is a UFD so primes are principal iff they have height one, iff the localization has dimension $1$ iff the localization is normal of dimension $1$ iff the localization is a DVR.

Comment: @Aphelli thanks a lot for that counterexample, I will be thinking about it